# Similar statements need duplication removed

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would you refactor this?

`ExpensiveQuery` must only run when necessary.

```
DECLARE @city VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @status INT


IF @status = 5
BEGIN
    SELECT c.Name, c.Phone
    FROM Customers c
    WHERE c.City = @city
    AND c.Status = 5
END
ELSE IF @status = 10
BEGIN
    SELECT c.Name, c.Phone
    FROM Customers c
    WHERE c.City = @city
    AND c.Status = 10
    AND c.SignUpDate NOT IN (EXEC ExpensiveQuery)
END
```

Comment: The actual query is about 30 lines, 28 of which are the same most of the time.  Maybe this is a time when things don't need to be dry

Comment: I think konijin's answer below is as good as this snippet is going to get. Have you considered perhaps posting `ExpensiveQuery` for review? Perhaps we can have more impact on your code base in general that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure your quest for de-duplication is warranted,
the only approach I know of is this:

```
DECLARE @city VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @status INT

SELECT c.Name, c.Phone
FROM Customers c
WHERE c.City = @city
AND c.Status = @status
AND ( ( c.Status = 5 )
OR    ( c.Status = 10  AND c.SignUpDate NOT IN (EXEC ExpensiveQuery) ) )
```

Comment: `c.status = @status` is common to both branches. Is that duplication intentional?

Comment: It was, because I had not considered taking it out

Comment: Its a contrived example, I realize now that its redundant.

Comment: This idea works but I found that ExpensiveQuery was being executed even when Status was != 10

Comment: Really.. I would have thought that SQL Server would be more conservative..

Comment: how did you find out that it still runs the Expensive query?  can you show us a screenshot?  must be in the query plan or something?

Comment: Its in the query plan and it makes the query take minutes instead of seconds.

Comment: Keeping in mind as well that in reality the above example would have several or statements like  this.

Comment: SQL Server evaluation order is non-deterministic, so you cannot count on short-circuiting to work.  In the expression (A AND B), the query optimizer may elect to evaluate A first, B first, or both simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

You could put the duplicated part into a CTE

and then run it like this

```
WITH CommonTable AS 
(
    SELECT 
        c.Name
        , c.Phone
        , c.signUpDate
    FROM
        Customers c
    WHERE 
        c.City = @city 
        AND c.Status = @status
)
SELECT * FROM 
(
    IF @status = 10 
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM CommonTable WHERE CommonTable.SignUpDate NOT IN (EXEC ExpensiveQuery) 
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM CommonTable
    END
)
```

Comment: Perhaps you encountered a comma-first hater ;)